# Syntax to dtexec multiple SSIS packages

Tags: ssis, package, dtexec

What is the syntax for calling multiple SSIS packages (Package1, Package2, Package3) using dtexec in a bat file?

```
dtexec /f "C:\Package1.dtsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

To start the packages in sequence, I guess that you just can create a batch file where you start them.

```
dtexec /f "C:\Package1.dtsx"
dtexec /f "C:\Package2.dtsx"
dtexec /f "C:\Package3.dtsx"
```

To start them in parallel you can workaround the limitation of dtexec by calling it in separate command. I found this post that explains that: http://www.rafael-salas.com/2010/07/ssis-how-to-run-set-of-packages.html

You can create a batch of packages where you cmd.exe for each of them.

- Executable = C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
- Arguments = /c start Dtexec /FILE "C:\MyPackages\ChildPackage.dtsx"

Comment: Sorry, I should be clearer. My goal is to start all the packages in sequence. How can I accomplish that using dtexec?